# Hartshorne's notation $s: U \to \coprod_{\mathfrak{p} \in U} A_{\mathfrak{p}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I understand that Hartshorne is defining the sections on an open set of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ as functions from the points $\mathfrak{p} \in U$ into their localizations $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ that are locally induced by ring elements. Still, I question his choice of notation '$\coprod$'. If we really must convey this definition in the notation of the functions then shouldn't we say that $s$ maps $U$ into $\oplus A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, the direct sum of the rings? The direct sum actually behaves somewhat like the 'disjoint union' and then we would just have to require that $s(\mathfrak{p})$ is contained in the image of $\theta: A_{\mathfrak{p}} \hookrightarrow \oplus A_{\mathfrak{q}}$ by the canonical injection for each $\mathfrak{p} \in U$. In contrast, doesn't $\coprod$ denote the tensor product in the category of commutative rings? This can't possibly be what we want.

Comment: You may wish to consider adding an appropriate tag of category theory.

Comment: Strictly speaking, he's just rewriting what it means to be an element of the product $\prod_{\mathfrak{p} \in U} A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_products)) in a suggestive way and then putting some conditions on the tuples. It definitely makes _sense_.

Comment: If he had chosen product notation as you did it would make perfect sense, The alternative I described with direct sum works our exactly the same with direct product instead. However, it seems that the upside down product symbol designates coproduct (tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$), which is nothing at all like the product or sum. So what could he possibly mean to suggest with this choice?

Comment: It does not mean tensor product. Did you follow the link to Wikipedia? I think that explains things.

Comment: So $\coprod$ was chosen because of it's resemblance to the union symbol?

Comment: As Qiaochu says, Hartshorne really means the coproduct (= disjoint union) of sets.

Comment: ok now i understand. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Hartshorne means the disjoint union of sets. There is no such thing as the direct sum of infinitely many rings (the result has a multiplication but no unit in general).

This definition comes from thinking of sheaves in terms of their [etale spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#The_.C3.A9tal.C3.A9_space_of_a_sheaf) and sections of sheaves as literally sections of the projection from the etale space. The etale space of the structure sheaf of $\text{Spec } A$, as a set, is the disjoint union of its stalks, which are the localizations $A_p$.